# Add a sensible sorting to developer story company listings (and social graph tags)

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I work for a company which has plenty of Stack Overflow users, and its [developer story company page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/26950/toptal?storyType=1) would benefit from a couple of improvements:

1. It's not clear to me what the sort order is: creation date/Id? random order based on SQL Server's whims? In any case either sorting by name or by reputation would be better. Ideally this can be done with tabs similar to the user page

   [image: sorting suggestion]
2. Sharing this page on social networks is a bit crap because its social graph tags are not filled in correctly or at all (it's defaulting to the minimum set in the master page):

   [image: social graph tags]

Can we get this couple of tiny, but valuable changes?

Comment: Ewwwww code image!

Comment: But hand drawn red circle makes it an OK post.

Comment: FWIW it looks like the sorting is based on "date joined SO"

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, code image is ok if answerer wouldn't use it anyway. It's only a customer complain after all..

Comment: Don't you work at stackoverflow - why don't you fix it?

Comment: @JonH https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291152/so-long-sklivvz