# The Stack Overflow DS company page gave me the power of bilocation

Tags: bug, developer-story

While I'm very flattered and feel more important, I do think I don't deserve to be given the power of [bilocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilocation).

I think someone forgot a `DISTINCT` somewhere, because I appear both on [page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/1/stack-overflow?storytype=1&page=1) and [page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/1/stack-overflow?storytype=1&page=2) of the Stack Overflow Developer story company page:

[image]
[image]

While you are fixing it, can you also fix the sort as requested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350239/add-a-sensible-sorting-to-developer-story-company-listings-and-social-graph-tag) with +33 votes?

Finally, shouldn't that page show a difference between current employees and alumni?

Comment: Also, are we sure that all the people in that list are legit? Could be but please check

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of noise in that list. I guess that's to be expected since we don't do any sort of verification of employment (as far as I know), and it's not that much different than someone just putting junk on their resume or LinkedIn or something, but it does end up looking dodgy as hell. :/

Comment: I'm not on any of those pages. If anyone asks, I'm telling them I'm the sklivvz on page #2

Comment: You should be aware that transcontinental bilocation is common on SO :)

Comment: One of these Skilvvzii is not like the other...

Comment: Could also be a bad `JOIN`.

Comment: There's no bad join. Just bad DBAs.

Comment: @nicomp: Why do you think SO Careers exists?  Everyone pretends it's about serving developers and employers who pay for access, but the true goal is to help SO hire the best and brightest.  The rest is just making someone else pay for it.

Comment: @BenVoigt The same reason a machine tool exists: to make more machine tools.

Comment: @nicomp I'm going to embroider a sampler with that quote and give it to my DBA.

Comment: @MrBoJangles You are now my favorite person on SO.